# How Do I Use DisplayLabel.Text In Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make certain text appear in the label when a button is clicked, but I always get the error `The name DisplayLabel does not exist in the current context. This is my Code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chapter_2_HW
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void sinisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Left");
        }

        private void mediumButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dexterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void instructionLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void translateLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayLabel.Text = "Goodbye";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a display label in your form?

Comment: Are you sure your label is correctly named in the designer?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz; I have a label in form, I haven't seen a display label in the toolbox

Comment: @kookman98, set the name of the label as "DisplayLabel"

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault; I am trying to click on the mediumButton, and get translateLabel to display something. I don't know the proper syntax for `DisplayLabel`, so I don't know where to put it or how it even works, sorry.

Comment: The syntax is `X.Text`, where _X_ is the name assigned to your control. By default, your label will be named `label1`. You need to change its name in the designer to `DisplayLabel` (Properties -> Name) or change your code to `label1.Text`. The important thing here is to match the code-behind name with the one in the designer.